# Get value of textbox into view component without using begin form or post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a list within a dropdown of users a person can say share a case with above that is a form field

This is called update info and is just a text area field.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <textarea id="updateInfo" name="updateInfo" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Question is without using post back or ajax begin form how does one get only the value from UpdateInfo textbox to a data attritube of the anchor tag.

```
@foreach (var allUsers in Model) {
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="MisObjects" asp-action="ShareCase"  asp-route- 
    id="@allUsers.Id.ToString()" >@allUsers.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant() 
     @allUsers.LastName.ToUpperInvariant()</a>
 }
```

To overcomplicate things I have the list of users in a view component

```
<li class="nav-item dropdowntest">
    <a class="nav-linkb dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Share Case
    </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShareButtonList", new { caseId = Model.Id ,Text=UpdateInfo.Text ///how do i do this })

  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The anchor tag and view component has been rendered html when the app run.You could only change the html data by using js when you fill the data to the textarea.If you want to pass the data which depend on the textarea to the view component.This is impossible.

Comment: I ended up removing the view component it was over complicating the issue and now have it working on  a form submit